# How to scan for wireless networks fast

Tags: bash, shell-script, wifi

I have written a script which scans for wifi networks with

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
```

and put the SSIDs in a file.

Is there a similar tool wich works a bit faster?

Comment: Have you tried `airodump-ng`?

Comment: It is possible to save the airodump-ng output in file??

Comment: `iwlist wlan1 scan`, `nmcli dev wifi`…

Comment: ^ a little bit slow...

Comment: You can store a command `wod-ele-da-cmd` output to a plain text file `wod-ele-da-file` by `wod-ele-da-cmd > wod-ele-da-file`

Comment: O.K.. I did it with ´iwlist´ and saved it to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First option: airodump-ng**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776383/reading-realtime-output-from-airodump-ng

```
airodump-ng [MONITOR MODE DEVICE] -w [FILE] --write-interval 5 -o csv
```

This will write a file [FILE]-01.csv which updates every 5 seconds. You have to kill the airodump-ng process when you want to stop scanning.

**Second option: iwlist**

```
iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Cell |Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID' > [FILE]
```

This will save a list of available networks with details to [FILE]. The process takes 1-5 seconds.

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/questions/75625/how-do-i-scan-for-wireless-access-points

You need root privileges for both options.